# Error when i try to fill a column depending of another in the same table

Tags: r

When I try to use the following command:

```
dim_Programacao$Classificacao_Programa[dim_Programacao$Classificacao == "P"] <- "Programa"
```

[image: Here is an example of the table]

It was supposed to work, but instead, the column "Classificacao_Programa" stays the same, with the value 0.

I already did use `stringAsFactor = FALSE`, but the result stays the same.

Comment: It is better to post the sample data as text and not an image.  Using `dput` is even better as it will allow others to easily load the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case I suppose you need to use something similar to trim. You can use regex:

```
dim_Programacao$Classificacao_Programa[gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "", dim_Programacao$Classificacao) == "P"] <- "Programa"
```

Comment: Or use directly `trimws()`

Comment: Spot on, Ricardo! Thanks :)